# Why this random variable is uniformly distributed?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Here is an exercise.

> Suppose that people arrive at a bus stop in accordance with a Poisson
>   process with rate $\lambda$. The bus departs at time $t$. Let $X$
>   denote the total amount of waiting time of all those who get on the
>   bus at time $t$. Let $N(t)$ denote the number of arrivals by time $t$.

Now we want to calculate $E[X\;|\;N(t)]$.

The solution says that the waiting time of each person, $T$, is uniformly distribute in $(0,t)$. So $E[X\;|\;N(t)=n]=n\int_0^t(t-s)\frac{1}{t}ds$.

My question is, why $T$ is uniformly distribute? If people arrivals obeying Poisson process, shouldn't $T$ obeying exponential distribute with parameter $\lambda$?

Comment: No because $T$ depends on buses, not people.

Answer (score 4):

This is all the difference there is between building Poisson processes from *ordered* samples or from *unordered* ones. The description recalled in the post, based on exponentially distributed interarrival times, uses the former. The latter stipulates that, once conditioned by $[N(t)=n]$ for some $n\geqslant1$, the (unordered) set of the $n$ arrival times is distributed as a sample of $n$ i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed on $(0,t)$.

In particular, the mean sum of these arrival times is $n$ times the mean of a random variable uniform on $(0,t)$, that is, $\frac12nt$. Since the mean of $N(t)$ is $\lambda t$, the (unconditional) mean sum of these arrival times is $\frac12\lambda t^2$.

To get an idea of the reason why the two descriptions mentioned above are equivalent, let us recover the distribution of the first arrival time $T$ from the second description.

If $N(t)=0$, all we know is that $T\gt t$. If $N(t)=n$ with $n\geqslant1$, then $T$ is distributed as the infimum of $n$ i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed on $(0,t)$, hence, for every $s$ in $(0,t)$, $\mathbb P(T\geqslant s\mid N(t)=n)=(1-s/t)^n$. Using Bayes formula and assuming that $N(t)$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda$, one gets for every $s\leqslant t$,
$$
\mathbb P(T\geqslant s)=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\mathbb P(T\geqslant s\mid N(t)=n)\mathbb P(N(t)=n),
$$
that is,
$$
\mathbb P(T\geqslant s)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}+\sum_{n\geqslant1}(1-s/t)^n\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^n/n!=\mathrm e^{-\lambda s}.
$$
This shows that, at least on $(0,t)$, $T$ is distributed as an exponential random variable with parameter $\lambda$.

Comment: Nice explanation. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Since the rate is given as a constant $\lambda$, this is a [Homogeneous Poisson Process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_process#Homogeneous). Conceptually, a Homogeneous Poisson Process has a probability $\lambda\Delta t$ of occurring in any infinitesimal time period $\Delta t$. That is, the arrival of a person in any infinitesimal interval of time $[t,t+\Delta t]$ is $\lambda\Delta t$. Thus, a person is just as likely to arrive in a given interval $[t_0,t_0+\Delta t]$ as any other interval $[t_1,t_1+\Delta t]$, which is simply a way of saying that the arrival times are uniformly distributed. Since the arrival time, $a$, is uniform within $[0,t]$, the wait time, which is $t-a$ would also be uniformly distributed.